# Linear interpolation (lm) in R, weird behavior

Tags: r, lm, linear-interpolation

Using R 3.2.2, I found a weird behavior running a simple linear interpolation. The first data frame gives the right result :

```
test<-data.frame(dt=c(36996616, 36996620, 36996623, 36996626), value=c(1,2,3,4))
lm(value~dt, test)$coefficients

  (Intercept)            dt 
-1.114966e+07  3.013699e-01
```

By incrementing the dt variable, the coefficient is now NA :

```
test$dt<-test$dt+1
lm(value~dt, test)$coefficients

(Intercept)          dt 
        2.5          NA
```

Any idea why ? Seems there is an overflow somewhere ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

I found some better information about this issue.

You can get `NA` coefficients if the *predictors* are perfectly correlated.  This seems to be an unusual case since we only have one predictor.  So in this case, `dt` appears to be linearly related with the intercept.

We can find linearly dependent variables using `alias`.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112442/what-are-aliased-coefficients

In the first example

```
test<-data.frame(dt=c(36996616, 36996620, 36996623, 36996626), value=c(1,2,3,4))
fit1 <- lm(value ~ dt, test)
alias(fit1)
Model :
value ~ dt
```

No linearly dependent terms.  But in the second example

```
test$dt <- test$dt + 1
fit2 <- lm(value ~ dt, test)
alias(fit2)
Model :
value ~ dt

Complete :
   [,1]       
dt 147986489/4
```

Which appears to show a linearly dependent relationship between `dt` and the `intercept`.

Additional information on how `lm` deals with a reduced-rank model: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-February/018512.html.

`lm` does not invert X'X https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-January/152456.html, but I still think the below is helpful to show the singularity of X'X.

```
x <- matrix(c(rep(1, 4), test$dt), ncol=2)
y <- test$value

b <- solve(t(x) %*% x) %*% t(x) %*% y
Error in solve.default(t(x) %*% x) : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 7.35654e-30
```

The default `tol` in `lm.fit` is 1e-7, which is the tolerance for computing linear dependencies in `qr` decomposition.

```
qr(t(x) %*% x)$rank
[1] 1
```

If you reduce this, you will get a parameter estimate for `dt`.

```
# decrease tol in qr
qr(t(x) %*% x, tol = 1e-31)$rank
[1] 2

# and in lm
lm(value~dt, test, tol=1e-31)$coefficients
  (Intercept)            dt 
-1.114966e+07  3.013699e-01
```

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86001/simple-linear-regression-fit-manually-via-matrix-equations-does-not-match-lm-o for details on the matrix algebra in simple linear regression.

Comment: Yes, `biglm` function from `biglm` packages gives the same answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer, and indeed it works well with the `tol` option. The thing is I got the same issue with any set of values for  y, ie `test<-data.frame(dt=c(36996616, 36996620, 36996623, 36996626), value=c(4655145,2,-51434,215))`. In that case, x and y are less correlated but same NA issue.

Comment: You are welcome.  The computational singular error I mentioned in the middle is derived from the design matrix `x`, specifically `solve(t(x) %*% x)`.    Run `qr(t(x) %*% x)$rank` and you get `1`, which means a singular matrix.  But if you run `qr(t(x) %*% x, tol=1e-31)$rank` you get `2`, which is a non-singular matrix.  That said, I am able to get both parameter estimates with your updated data, so I think the issue is a combination of the high correlation and the design matrix, which depends only on `dt`

Comment: @Yves I did some additional research and think I have some better information.  Have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Function `biglm` from `biglm` seems to directly manage this:

```
library(biglm)
test <- data.frame(dt=c(36996616, 36996620, 36996623, 36996626), 
                   value=c(1,2,3,4))
test$dt <- test$dt+1

coefficients(biglm(value ~ dt, test))
#   (Intercept)            dt 
# -1.114966e+07  3.013699e-01
```